# Linear Differential Equation with a Initial value

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The given equation is $$x^2y^{'}+xy^2=4y^2$$
with a initial value of $$y(1)=\frac{1}{5}$$ 
Using the integration factor formula I get
$$f(x)=4y^2$$
$$P(x)=x$$
$$\mu=e^{\int{xdx}}=e^\frac{x^2}{2}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\mu$ I get
$$e^\frac{x^2}{2}(x^2y^{'})+e^\frac{x^2}{2}(xy^2)=e^\frac{x^2}{2}(4y^2)$$
The left hand side is equal to $\frac{d}{dx}(y*\mu)$ and then I have to integrate but there is a y term on the right side of the problem and I don't know how to continue. Did I mistake the problem as a Linear Differential Equation or did I make an error in my arithmetic.

Comment: This is a nonlinear differential equation.  So the formulas for linear differential equations will probably not help you.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by $x^2y^2$ and you get separated variables $${y'\over y^2}= {4-x\over x^2}$$

So we have $$\int {dy\over y^2} = \int (4x^{-2}-x^{-1})dx$$

and thus $${-1\over y} = {-4\over x}-\ln x +c$$ so $$ y={1\over {4\over x}+\ln x -c}$$

From $y(1)=1/5$ we get $5=4-c$ so $c=-1$ and thus $$y={x\over 4+x\ln x+x}$$

Comment: This answer is of no use to you?

Answer (score 0):

Ypu made a mistake. You first need to put the differential equation in the classical form
$$y'+P(x)y=g(x)$$
And the integrating factor only works for linear differential equation. here it's not the case. You have $y^2$
$$x^2y^{'}+xy^2=4y^2$$
$$y^{'}+\color {red}{\frac {y^2}{x}}=4\dfrac {y^2}{x^2}$$
Your equation is separable. Separate both variables and integrate ( look at Aqua's good answer).